# Is the term "local unit shipping fee" correct?

Tags: vocabulary

We have "unit price" is the price of 1 item only. And this price does not include shipping fee.

I am using the term "local unit shipping fee" to express that is the shipping fee of 1 item only and that fee is just applied for local area.

Is that a correct way to express that idea?

What is the word that English people use to express that idea? do you use "unit local shipping fee" or "local shipping unit fee"?

Comment: I would suggest *The per-unit shipping fee for local delivery*.

Comment: It would be confusing to call it the "per-unit" shipping fee unless it is multiplied by the number of units.

Comment: i need a much shorter term, can u come up something shorter

Answer (score 1):

We typically use "shipping fee" to refer to individual item shipping costs. If you want to be extremely explicit then "shipping fee (per unit)" would work. "Local shipping fee (per unit)" also works.

If you need something shorter you could trim out "fee": "Local shipping (per unit)".

Comment: the problem is that I also have shipping fee for many items, so i want to use "unit shipping fee" to make it clear for 1 unit & "shipping fee" for many units. If we say "Total Shipping Fee" then it sound strange

Comment: Just use (per unit) after the unit specific shipping fees and (per shipment) after the fees that are only applied once.